# How to add links in datatables from different JSON Values in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

We are getting JSOn Response which is getting populated to HTML using Datatables. But i am unable to figure out how to put link which is coming in different field to object.

Following is JSON data received after Ajax call:

```
[
  "filename":"maha.pdf",
  "link":"http://maha.com/maha.pdf",
}
]
```

Following is code where data is displayed

```
<table id="dataLink">
        <thead>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Following is Ajax call and corresponding method call:

```
my.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'getFileList.json',
        data: {
            '_CONV_ID': $('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val(),
        },
        success: function (jsondata) {
            console.log(jsondata);
            fileData.fileShow.clear().rows.add(jsondata).draw();
        },

    });



 fileData.fileShow.= $('#dataLink').DataTable($.extend({}, fileCommon.tableTemplate, {
            asStripClasses: [], // No stripes
            width:     "100%",
            columnDefs: [
                {"width": "20%", targets: 0},
            ],
            columns: [
                {"data": "filename"} <- I want to embed it to <a href="->link<-">fileName</a> but it does not work and says too much recursion
            ]
    }));
```

Comment: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns. Go through the `mRender` option.

Comment: Thanks for response. How to use mrender in above scenario. Say 
"mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
       return '<a href="?action=student_report&studentUID='+ full.DT_RowId + '">' + data + '</a>';

Comment: Its all there just go through the options. They are available with examples.

Comment: Yes looking. Till now not able to figure out to adjust in above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`aoColumnDefs` would be something like this -

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ {
  "aTargets": [ 0 ],
  "mData": "filename",
  "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
    return '<a href="'+full.link+'">'+data+'</a>';
  }
} ]
```

Comment: Thanks Bos3. It seems to be the above will come inside  columns: [ ]  and then i may remove {"data": "filename"} . Trying

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: Replacing `columnDefs` & `columns` may help.

Comment: OK. Suppose we need to display one more field other then {"data": "filename"}; then need to repeat whole "aoColumnDefs"?

Comment: Then check `aoColumns`.

Comment: Vuowwwwwww.... the above one worked No need to remove Columns and it should be filnavn not data Great THANKS A LOT.